# Catching currentindex of a QComboBox

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a popup list(*QComboBox*) that contains three elements, and I want to display a *toolTip*(via the *setToolTip* called on the QComboBox) depending on the item's number.

Displaying the toolTip works fine, but it is static, it doesn't change when the user selects an item different than the first one.

The idea is to get the current item number each time the user selects an item, and pass that item' number to the method *algorithms_info*

The signature of the method *algorithms_info* is:

```
def algorithms_info(self, a=0):
```

So I set a signal:

```
self.algoList.connect(self.algoList, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("currentItemChanged(int)")), self.algorithms_info(int))
```

When I run the script the following error is displayed:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

The error is in the signal declaration, but if you have any suggestions on doing this in another way, then I will be pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `self.algoList.currentItemChanged.connect(self.algorithms_info)`. I think after this, you will be fine .

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tooltip on each item, so there's no need for signals:

```
for index in range(10):
    combo.setItemData(index, 'Item (%d)' % index, QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole)
```